# Unable to find python api for google cloud TPU

Tags: google-cloud-platform, tpu

I am looking for any python api reference for creating/maintaining google cloud tpu with python api. Could someone please help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check this [official doc](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/quickstart)? that one is a Quickstart with Cloud TPU and Python. Also, there are several guide on how to use the API in [here](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/tutorials).